# How to create an index that has NULLS LAST in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I read https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html.

I don't see how to create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON users (id DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Did not see docs on how to create and index with `NULLS LAST`.

Rails 4.2.10

PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Record now supports `NULLS LAST` in an index with the `order` argument:

```
add_index(
    :my_table,
    [:my_column],
    order: { my_column: "DESC NULLS LAST" }
)
```

Comment: I gather you are referring to Rails 7.

Comment: This brings up an important questions about SO, which is how to manage the best answer as the version of the relevant language or framework changes. Perhaps answers should have a version tag, or at least mention the version in the answer.

Comment: @BSeven I didn't confirm which version of Rails this was introduced in. In [tag:python], we will often mention the version or a link to the docs, or both.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe Rails migrations support index options `NULLS LAST`.  You'll likely need to have raw SQL.

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #add custom index
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE INDEX index_users_on_id_nulls_last ON users (id DESC NULLS LAST);
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP INDEX index_users_on_id_nulls_last;
    SQL
  end
end
```